# Making a dropdown and getting the value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a many-to-many relation between my User model and my Project model for the purpose of assigning projects to users. I'm now trying to impement the feature for actual assignment using a dropdown containing the projects on the edit user page. My code looks like this, but I can't seem to figure out how send the selected value back to the controller once the button is clicked:

```
<div class="input-group my-2">
  <%= collection_select('user', 'project', Project.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true) %>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <%= link_to '<div class="btn btn-outline-primary">Toggle access to selected project</div>'.html_safe, toggle_project_access_user_url %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the suggestions for JS I've found, but I think I'm missing some knowlegde on how to implement the functionality completely with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working with Javascript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) covers this.

Use [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) to set up a form with `data-remote=true`. Then proceed as normal.

```
form_with url: toggle_project_access_user_url, method: :patch do |f|
  f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true)
  f.submit("Toggle access to selected project")
end
```

This will send a POST to toggle_project_access_user_url with a hidden _method input indicating it's a PATCH. Use a hook on `ajax:success` to update the page.

Comment: The line: 
`f.collection_select(:user, :project_id, Project.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true)` 
had to be changed to: 
`f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true)` 
due to the `form_with` version of `collection_select` having the first field implicitly, but otherwise this solution is working perfectly! Thank you!